# HighChart Libraries Android: HIOptions not found in HIChartView

Tags: android, charts, highcharts

I am trying to integrate highcharts in my android app (inside fragment) but I am getting this error every time:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: HIOptions not found in HIChartView
```

Here is my onCreateView Method:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_layout, null);
        return parentView;
    }
```

How I am getting chart view:

```
chartView = parentView.findViewById(R.id.hc);
```

I am calling chart API to get to data after getting a response, I am setting options but it is giving me the same error, below is the code snippets how am I setting chart:

```
                HIOptions options = new HIOptions();

                HIChart chart = new HIChart();
                chart.setType("column");
                options.setChart(chart);

                HIExporting hiExporting = new HIExporting();
                hiExporting.setEnabled(false);
                options.setExporting(hiExporting);

                List<BarChartSeries> seriesList = barChartModel.getSeries();
                if (!seriesList.isEmpty()) {

                    final HIXAxis xAxis = new HIXAxis();

                    HITitle xAxisTitle = new HITitle();
                    xAxisTitle.setText(getString(R.string.year));

                    xAxis.setTitle(xAxisTitle);

                    XAxisDto xAxisDto = barChartModel.getxAxis();
                    List<String> stringList1 = xAxisDto.getCategories();

                    ArrayList<String> xAxisList = new ArrayList<>();
                    xAxisList.addAll(stringList1);
                    xAxis.setCategories(xAxisList);
                    xAxis.setCrosshair(new HICrosshair());

                    ArrayList<HIXAxis> axes = new ArrayList<>();
                    axes.add(xAxis);

                    options.setXAxis(axes);


                    HIYAxis yAxis = new HIYAxis();
                    yAxis.setMin(0);

                    HITitle yAxisTitle = new HITitle();
                    yAxisTitle.setText(getString(R.string.no_of_cases));

                    yAxis.setTitle(yAxisTitle);

                    ArrayList<HIYAxis> yaxes = new ArrayList<>();
                    yaxes.add(yAxis);


                    options.setYAxis(yaxes);

                    HITooltip tooltip = new HITooltip();
                    tooltip.setHeaderFormat("<span style=\"font-size:10px\">{point.key}</span><table>");
                    tooltip.setPointFormat("<span style=\"font-size:10px\">{point.key}</span><table>");
                    tooltip.setFooterFormat("</table>");
                    tooltip.setShared(true);
                    tooltip.setUseHTML(true);
                    options.setTooltip(tooltip);

                    HIPlotOptions plotOptions = new HIPlotOptions();
                    HIColumn hiColumn = new HIColumn();
                    hiColumn.setPointPadding(0.2);
                    hiColumn.setBorderWidth(0);
                    plotOptions.setColumn(hiColumn);
                    options.setPlotOptions(plotOptions);

                    ArrayList<HISeries> dataSetList = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (seriesList.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < seriesList.size(); i++) {

                            BarChartSeries barChartSeries = seriesList.get(i);
                            String name = barChartSeries.getName();
                            List<Data> dataList = barChartSeries.getData();

                            HIColumn series1 = new HIColumn();
                            series1.setName(name);

                            List<String> stringList = xAxisDto.getCategories();
                            ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
                            ArrayList<Long> doubleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                            if (stringList != null) {

                                for (int j = 0; j < stringList.size(); j++) {
                                    String cat = stringList.get(j);
                                    int count = 0;

                                    for (int ij = 0; ij < dataList.size(); ij++) {
                                        Data data = dataList.get(ij);

                                        if (data.getYear().equalsIgnoreCase(cat)) {
                                            count++;
                                            yVals.add(new BarEntry(ij, data.getCount()));
                                            doubleArrayList.add(data.getCount());
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (count == 0) {
                                        yVals.add(new BarEntry(yVals.size() + 1, 0));
                                        doubleArrayList.add(0l);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            series1.setData(doubleArrayList);
                            dataSetList.add(series1);
                        }

                    }

                    options.setSeries(dataSetList);
                    ArrayList<HIColor> hiColors = new ArrayList<>();
                    hiColors.add(HIColor.initWithHexValue("FF0000"));
                    hiColors.add(HIColor.initWithHexValue("FFA500"));
                    hiColors.add(HIColor.initWithHexValue("808080"));
                    options.setColors(hiColors);

                    HITitle title = new HITitle();
                    title.setText("");
                    options.setTitle(title);

                    HISubtitle subtitle = new HISubtitle();
                    subtitle.setText("");

                    options.setSubtitle(subtitle);

                    HICredits hiCredits = new HICredits();
                    hiCredits.setEnabled(false);

                    options.setCredits(hiCredits);
                    chartView.setOptions(options);
```

What am I missing here? Or How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue.

Follow below steps to resolve the issues:

1. When you fragment view is visible
2. Get highchart Id

   > chartView = parentView.findViewById(R.id.hc);
3. Set empty options to chartView:

   > ```
   > HIOptions options = new HIOptions();
   >
   > chartView.setOptions(options);
   > ```
4. Once you get the data from your API set options to chartView again and call reload method:

   > ```
   > chartView.setOptions(options);
   > chartView.reload();
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency again

```
implementation 'com.highsoft.highcharts:highcharts:7.0.3'
```

in the build.gradle file(app)

In my case It worked Well